# My computer doesn't detect wifi anymore

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

So, my computer was running sweet and after I restarted it wasn't detecting my wifi anymore. I'm sure the wifi is there, my other computers get it.

Configuration:
Windows 7
Gateway NV53
Linksys Router

Please, I really need to fix it.

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Comment: Did you try another restart or two? Remember its Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Without more information, I can only give you standard troubleshooting steps:

1. Is there a physical switch or function key on the laptop that disables wi-fi? According to Gateway, there's [a capacitive button that toggles wi-fi on and off](http://support.gateway.com/s/notebook/2009/gateway/nv/nv52/NV52ivr3.shtml).
2. [Download the latest driver and software updates for your laptop from Gateway](http://support.gateway.com/support/drivers/dlcenter.asp?cmpid=topnav).
3. Do a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-System-Restore) to before the problem occurred.
4. Back up your data, then re-install Windows.

Comment: On more than one occasion I've come across, number one was the culprit!

Comment: I was hoping that "re-install Windows" never ever will reach SU...

Comment: @naxa It's certainly not a first option, but given how little information we had on the matter, it was the best I could suggest at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a similar problem but with a Vista installation in something called "[BROADCAST flag in DHCP discovery packets](http://askbobrankin.com/cannot_connect_to_wireless_router.html)". You can check [Windows official forums](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/8c5cad75-0612-4912-9473-09ecc5f0fd15) or [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928233) for more detailed information about this issue.